# MATCH for a node name using cypher in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm wondering if it is possible to MATCH for a node by it's name.
I dont want to match through properties, labels or connections. I want to store a node "Start Time", and retrieve it's value later on. Can i MATCH this one Node without assigning a name property ?

Working Create Query:

```
CREATE (Start Time:timestamp {name: "Time Stamp", time: 0239213021312 })
```

Working Match Query:

```
"MATCH (n: timestamp {name:'Time Stamp'})
```

Could i also query for this node though ?

Create Query:

```
CREATE (Start Time:timestamp {time: 0239213021312 })
```

Comment: To note, what you refer to as a "node name" is actually a variable, and variables are not persisted to the graph, and as such are not accessible outside of the query.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

You can find a node by its native ID, **as long as the node is never deleted and you use the same neo4j database instance that generated that ID**.

When a database instance creates a node, the instance will assign the node a native ID that the instance is not using at that time. When a database instance deletes a node, the instance can assign the deleted node's native ID to another node created later.

Assuming the above criteria are met:

- If the node already exists, you can get its native ID once (as shown below), and then hard-code the native ID in the queries that need it. (In this case, the native ID will not change even if you later remove the `name` property.)

  ```
  MATCH (startTime:timestamp {name: "Time Stamp"})
  RETURN ID(startTime);
  ```
- You can get a node's native ID at the time you create it (as shown below), and then hard-code the native ID in the queries that need it. (In this case, there is no need to even specify a `name` property.)

  ```
  CREATE (startTime:timestamp {time: 0239213021312})
  RETURN ID(startTime);
  ```

If the native ID is, say, 123, then you can get the node later via:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE ID(n) = 123
...
```

On the other hand, if the node might be deleted, then it will have to have some property with a unique value that you can query for.

Comment: but the first match query, that i use to retrieve the native ID does still require the name propertie that i need to set first ?

Or does :
CREATE (Start Time:timestamp {time: 0239213021312 })

Provide the "name" for ? :
MATCH (startTime:timestamp {name: "Time Stamp"})

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully answer what I think you are asking.

Comment: yes that answers it well, and thanks for explaining the underlying logic behind it!